# Convert C language code to problem specification by computing the invariant of a program

Tags: formal-languages, software-verification

Suppose that you need to give a problem specification of some problem *P* and you have an implementation of *P*, in C.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can you obtain the formal specification of the problem if you compute the invariant of the external for cycle?
2. What is the relation between the specification and the C code invariant?

Answer (score 3):

You can not reconstruct the specification from just the code.

For one thing, you don't know whether the code is correct or not. For another, there are multiple possible specifications that are all compatible with the code.

For instance, consider the following function:

```
unsigned int f(unsigned int x) {
    return x+1;
}
```

Was the intended specification that `retval == x+1`?  Or that `retval > x`?  Or that `retval > 0`?  We can't tell.  There just isn't enough information to know.  (Ignore integer overflow for the moment.)